# How to fix very slow network access through proxy after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, proxy

I'm running a lab that sits behind a proxy server. We have been using Ubuntu 10.04.4, and getting reasonable internet transfer rates.

I'd like to upgrade to 12.04, but when I test it, attempts to connect to any site past the proxy take many minutes if they connect at all. Loading a home page routinely takes 30 minutes. It is getting an IP address from the DHCP server here in the lab, which is also the gateway. I can ping other machines in the lab.

If I connect this same machine to an unproxied connection it works fine. If I install 10.04 on this same machine, it works fine. Using 12.04 (and 13.04, btw) on several other machines also doesn't work

This problem exists whether I use a web site hostname, or an IP address. It happens on FTP as well as HTTP.

Things I've tried:

- Upgraded BIOS firmware (Dell Optiplex 745 v2.6.6)
- Built and installed newer tg3 NIC driver (3.133d)
- Restarted the proxy
- Disabled dnsmasq
- Set static IP address/gateway
- Added resolv.conf IPs to `/etc/hosts` file (to fix reports of nslookup failing)

Can anybody suggest how I can fix this, or at least begin to diagnose what the point of failure in this setup might be?

Answer (score 0):

Install the `iputils-tracepath` package, and use `tracepath` to make sure your MTU is no larger than any link's MTU.

Comment: When I run `tracepath` on a local IP, I get a 1 hop reply with an MTU of 1500. Whenever I use an IP address on the other side of the proxy, I get a repeating `no reply` response.

Comment: `tracepath` uses "some random UDP port", which isn't getting past the proxy.

Comment: Since you didn't mention it, have you inspected the `/var/log/` directory? `sudo grep eth0 /var/log/*`, replacing `eth0` with your NIC name. (sorry)

Comment: Are you using VLANs with your proxy? Should you be usiong a VLAN? What's `sudo ifconfig -a;ip route` show?